# How to count the trailing zeros in an array column in a PySpark dataframe without a UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with a column of an array with a fixed amount of integers.
How can I add to the df a column that contains the number of trailing zeros in the array?
I would like to avoid using a UDF for better performance.

For example, an input df:

```
>>> df.show()
+------------+
|           A|
+------------+
| [1,0,1,0,0]|
| [2,3,4,5,6]|
| [0,0,0,0,0]|
| [1,2,3,4,0]|
+------------+
```

And a wanted output:

```
>>> trailing_zeros(df).show()
+------------+-----------------+
|           A|   trailingZeros|
+------------+-----------------+
| [1,0,1,0,0]|                2|
| [2,3,4,5,6]|                0|
| [0,0,0,0,0]|                5|
| [1,2,3,4,0]|                1|
+------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Your Q&A would likely be better received if you provided a small example DataFrame along with the desired output.

Comment: Added an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you convert the array to a string, there are several new ways to get to the result:

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import length, regexp_extract, array_join, reverse
>>> 
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, [1, 2, 3]),
...                             (2, [2, 0]),
...                             (3, [0, 2, 3, 10]),
...                             (4, [0, 2, 3, 10, 0]),
...                             (5, [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]),
...                             (6, [0, 0, 0]),
...                             (7, [0, ]),
...                             (8, [10, ]),
...                             (9, [100, ]),
...                             (10, [0, 100, ]),
...                             (11, [])],
...                            schema=("id", "arr"))
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df.withColumn("trailing_zero_count",
...               length(regexp_extract(array_join(reverse(df.arr), ""), "^(0+)", 0))
...               ).show()
+---+----------------+-------------------+
| id|             arr|trailing_zero_count|
+---+----------------+-------------------+
|  1|       [1, 2, 3]|                  0|
|  2|          [2, 0]|                  1|
|  3|   [0, 2, 3, 10]|                  0|
|  4|[0, 2, 3, 10, 0]|                  1|
|  5| [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]|                  3|
|  6|       [0, 0, 0]|                  3|
|  7|             [0]|                  1|
|  8|            [10]|                  0|
|  9|           [100]|                  0|
| 10|        [0, 100]|                  0|
| 11|              []|                  0|
+---+----------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: [`array_join`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_join) is only available in version 2.4. You can do the same in older versions using [`concat_ws`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws).

Comment: Good suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

Since Spark 2.4 you can use Higher Order Function `AGGREGATE` to do that:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import reverse

(
  df.withColumn("arr_rev", reverse("A"))
  .selectExpr(
    "arr_rev", 
    "AGGREGATE(arr_rev, (1 AS p, CAST(0 AS LONG) AS sum), (buffer, value) -> (if(value != 0, 0, buffer.p), if(value=0, buffer.sum + buffer.p, buffer.sum)), buffer -> buffer.sum) AS result"
  )
)
```

assuming `A` is your array with numbers. Here just be careful with data types. I am casting the initial value to `LONG` assuming the numbers inside the array are also longs.

Comment: I accepted this as it performed ~10% faster than Oliver's answer, and ~900% faster than mine :)

Comment: Also a great thing about this and @Oliver's answer is that neither rely on knowing the length of the array.

Answer (score 3):

For Spark 2.4+, you should absolutely use [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) as shown in [@David Vrba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10298551/david-vrba)'s accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59194663/5858851).

For older models, here's an alternative to the regular expression approach.

First create some sample data:

```
import numpy as np
NROWS = 10
ARRAY_LENGTH = 5
np.random.seed(0)
data = [
    (np.random.randint(0, 100, x).tolist() + [0]*(ARRAY_LENGTH-x),) 
    for x in np.random.randint(0, ARRAY_LENGTH+1, NROWS)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["myArray"])
df.show()
#+--------------------+
#|             myArray|
#+--------------------+
#| [36, 87, 70, 88, 0]|
#|[88, 12, 58, 65, 39]|
#|     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
#|  [87, 46, 88, 0, 0]|
#|  [81, 37, 25, 0, 0]|
#|   [77, 72, 9, 0, 0]|
#|    [20, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
#|  [80, 69, 79, 0, 0]|
#|[47, 64, 82, 99, 88]|
#|   [49, 29, 0, 0, 0]|
#+--------------------+
```

Now iterate through your columns in reverse and return `null` if the column is `0`, or the `ARRAY_LENGTH-(index+1)` otherwise. Coalesce the results of this, which will return the value from the first non-null index - the same as the number of trailing 0's.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, col, when, lit, 
df.withColumn(
    "trailingZeroes",
    coalesce(
        *[
            when(col('myArray').getItem(index) != 0, lit(ARRAY_LENGTH-(index+1)))
            for index in range(ARRAY_LENGTH-1, -1, -1)
        ] + [lit(ARRAY_LENGTH)]
    )
).show()
#+--------------------+--------------+
#|             myArray|trailingZeroes|
#+--------------------+--------------+
#| [36, 87, 70, 88, 0]|             1|
#|[88, 12, 58, 65, 39]|             0|
#|     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|             5|
#|  [87, 46, 88, 0, 0]|             2|
#|  [81, 37, 25, 0, 0]|             2|
#|   [77, 72, 9, 0, 0]|             2|
#|    [20, 0, 0, 0, 0]|             4|
#|  [80, 69, 79, 0, 0]|             2|
#|[47, 64, 82, 99, 88]|             0|
#|   [49, 29, 0, 0, 0]|             3|
#+--------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

One more solution that works since Spark 1.5.0. Here we use `trim`, `rtrim`, `regexp_replace` and `length` to count the trailing zeros:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

to_string_expr = expr("regexp_replace(trim('[]', string(A)), ', ', '')")

df.withColumn("str_ar", to_string_expr) \
  .withColumn("trailingZeroes", expr("length(str_ar) - length(rtrim('0', str_ar))"))

# +---------------+--------------+
# |              A|trailingZeroes|
# +---------------+--------------+
# |[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]|             2|
# |[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|             0|
# |[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|             5|
# |[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]|             1|
# +---------------+--------------+
```

**Analysis:**

Starting from the inner to the outer most elements of `expr`:

1. `string(A)` converts array to its string representation i.e `[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]`.
2. `trim('[]', string(A))` removes leading `[` and trailing `]` respectively i.e `1, 0, 1, 0, 0`.
3. `regexp_replace(trim('[]', string(A)), ', ', '')` removes `,` between items to form the final string representation i.e `10100`.
4. `rtrim('0',regexp_replace(trim('[]', string(A)), ', ', ''))` trims the trailing zeros i.e: `101`.
5. Finally we get the length of the complete string and the trimmed one and we subtract them, this will give us the zero trailing length.

**UPDATE**

With the next code you can populate some data (borrowed from @pault's post) and measure the execution time for a large dataset using `timeit`.

Below I added some benchmarking for three of the posted methods. From the results we can conclude that there are some trends regarding the performance of the methods:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, regexp_replace, regexp_extract, reverse, length, array_join
import numpy as np
import timeit

NROWS = 1000000
ARRAY_LENGTH = 5
np.random.seed(0)
data = [
    (np.random.randint(0, 9, x).tolist() + [0]*(ARRAY_LENGTH-x),) 
    for x in np.random.randint(0, ARRAY_LENGTH+1, NROWS)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["A"])

def trim_func():
  to_string_expr = expr("regexp_replace(trim('[]', string(A)), ', ', '')")
  df.withColumn("str_ar", to_string_expr) \
    .withColumn("trailingZeroes", expr("length(str_ar) - length(rtrim('0', str_ar))")) \
    .show()
# Avg: 0.11089507223994588

def aggr_func():
  df.withColumn("arr_rev", reverse("A")) \
    .selectExpr("arr_rev", "AGGREGATE(arr_rev, (1 AS p, CAST(0 AS LONG) AS sum), \
                (buffer, value) -> (if(value != 0, 0, buffer.p), \
                if(value=0, buffer.sum + buffer.p, buffer.sum)), \
                buffer -> buffer.sum) AS result") \
   .show()
# Avg: 0.16555462517004343

def join_func():
  df.withColumn("trailing_zero_count", \
                length( \
                  regexp_extract( \
                    array_join(reverse(df["A"]), ""), "^(0+)", 0))) \
  .show()
# Avg:0.11372986907997984

rounds = 100
algs = {"trim_func" : trim_func, "aggr_func" : aggr_func, "join_func" : join_func}
report = list()
for k in algs:
  elapsed_time = timeit.timeit(algs[k], number=rounds) / rounds
  report.append((k, elapsed_time))

report_df = spark.createDataFrame(report, ["alg", "avg_time"]).orderBy("avg_time")
display(report_df)
```

[image]

The results showed that for a dataset of 1000000 rows and 100 executions the average execution time was is by **25%-30% lower for the string based processing (trim_func, join_func) methods**.

Without being sure about the exact reason, I can assume that the extra process time occurs from the complexity of the aggregate function itself. In any case, it seems that performance difference it is considerable.

The test was executed under the databricks community edition cluster/notebook.

Comment: Cool! Any chance for a runntime comparing the accepted answer?

Comment: @DavidVrba seems the most straight forward solution for Spark >= 2.4.0. The above approach is more suitable for older version. Both solutions use narrow transformations therefore I dont expect the performance difference to be noticeable although using `aggragate` together with `reverse` requires two array iterations when the above approach requires one and then it does some string processing. `trim` and `length` have very fast implementations when `string` and `regex_replace` are probably the most expensive. Therefore I dont think you will see huge differences during execution time

Comment: @DavidTaub I changed and optimised the previous code. I also did some tests on a large dataset of 1.000.000 rows (thanks to data generation code provided by @pault) it seems that the above combination of `trim` and `regex_replace`  executes by ~40% faster than the `aggragate` version.

Answer (score 0):

Using `getItem()`, and a double `when().otherwise()` for each item in the array, the reduce iterate over the array backwards build a negative counter of zeros. When the first non-zero value is encountered, the counter becomes positive and the counting stops. The reduce starts the counter with a pseudo count of -1, which is removed at the end.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from functools import reduce

cols = [F.col('myArray').getItem(index) for index in range(ARRAY_LENGTH-1, -1, -1)]
trailing_count_column = F.abs(reduce(lambda col1, col2: F.when((col1 < 0) & (col2 != 0), -col1).othewise(
    F.when((col1 < 0) & (col2 == 0), col1 - 1).otherwise(col1)), cols, F.lit(-1))) - 1

df = df.withColumn('trailingZeroes', trailing_count_column)
```